# How to add id attribute to mjml body components

Tags: html, email, mjml

I am presently using mjml to build email template, but i want to implement a anchor link feature in the email template, but i am stuck at the point where i need to add an id attribute to the mjml body component just as we add to html tags, and explanation will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this eventually, i used the  component which allows to add a raw html within it. [read more on the mj-raw component](https://mjml.io/documentation/#mj-raw)

```
<mj-raw> 
   <div id="customid"></div>
</mj-raw>
```

Comment: Glad that works. Do you want to use it, though? Lots of the email clients we all send emails to have very rudimentary support of current HTML standards. This is unlikely to be supported well. Maybe as low as 12.3% of email clients! https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=anchor Beware. Test thoroughly.